# If make eigenvalues of covariance more compact, does the correlation decrease?

Tags: linear-algebra

Denote the eigendecomposition of a covariance matrix $\Sigma$ as $\Sigma=Q\Lambda Q^T$. Because the eigenvalues $\Lambda$ indicate the scattering of the data points along the directions specified by $Q$, if I fix the $Q$, and make the eigenvalues more `compact', e.g. fix the mean value and make the eigenvalues have lower variance, I suppose that the correlation between variables should decrease as the distribution of data points is closer to a sphere. For example, the determinant of the correlation matrix corresponding to $\Sigma$ may increase. Is there any relevant theorem?

Edit:
If we use the determinant of the correlation matrix as an indicator of the correlation, then the question is whether there is some quantity that only contains the eigenvalues and is monotonic with respect to the determinant of the correlation matrix. Because the determinant of the correlation matrix reaches 1 only when the eigenvalues are all the same, intuitively that quantity should reflect the compactness of the eigenvalues.

Comment: "Making the eigenvalues have lower variance" is not the same as "making the eigenvalues closer to each other"/"make the distribution more sphere-like". Which do you mean?

Comment: @angryavian In fact I do not know how to describe the compactness of the eigenvalues, so I use the variance as an example. If the mean is fixed, reducing the variance will make the eigenvalues more closer to each other. If the ratio between different eigenvalues are closer to 1, the distribution of data points will be more sphere-like.